# How is it possible that a variable gets overwritten afterwards?

Tags: c#, xml, reference

I've got a strange Problem with reading existing XML Files. I Have a XML File with Steps as Elements. If there are two Steps inside the XML I want to display them in a ListBox.

I built a List<Steps> out of my XmlDoc:

```
var myStepList = new Steps(xmlDoc);
```

Then I count the Steps and go to Case 2 if there are two Steps inside.

```
switch (myStepList.amountOfSteps)
        {
            case 1:
                var StepData = myStepList.GetStepData(myStepList.stepList[0]);

                ListBoxSteps.Items.Add(StepData[0].ToString());
                TextBoxStepNo.Text = StepData[1].ToString();
                TextBoxStepColorCode.Text = StepData[2].ToString();
                break;

            case 2:
                var StepData1 = myStepList.GetStepData(myStepList.stepList[0]);

                var StepData2 = myStepList.GetStepData(myStepList.stepList[1]);

                ListBoxSteps.Items.Add(StepData1[0].ToString());
                ListBoxSteps.Items.Add(StepData2[0].ToString());
                TextBoxStepNo.Text = StepData1[1].ToString();
                TextBoxStepNo2.Text = StepData2[1].ToString();
                TextBoxStepColorCode.Text = StepData1[2].ToString();
                TextBoxStepColorCode2.Text = StepData2[2].ToString();
                break;
        }
```

When `Stepdata2` is defined with the right content, it overwrites `StepData1`. I dont know why because before it has the right content.

here is my class Steps:

```
class Steps
{
    private List<XElement> StepList;

    private readonly XAttribute[] StepData;

    private int AmountOfSteps = 0;

    private readonly int AmountOfStepAttributes = 3;

    public Steps(XmlDoc xmlDoc)
    {
        StepList = xmlDoc.GetStepList();
        StepData = new XAttribute[AmountOfStepAttributes];
    }

    public XAttribute[] GetStepData(XElement step)
    {
        StepData[0] = step.Attribute("name");
        StepData[1] = step.Attribute("stepNo");
        StepData[2] = step.Attribute("colorCode");

        return StepData;
    }

    public List<XElement> stepList
    {
        get { return StepList; }
    }

    public int amountOfSteps
    {
        get
        {
            AmountOfSteps = stepList.Count();

            return AmountOfSteps;
        }            
    }

    public int amountStepAttributes
    {
        get { return AmountOfStepAttributes; }
    }
```

This is my class called XmlDoc:

```
 class XmlDoc 
{
    private List<string> ListFileNames;

    private XDocument XDoc;

    private XAttribute RootAttribute;

    private List<XElement> StepList;

    public XmlDoc()
    {
        StepList = new List<XElement>();
        ListFileNames = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> GetXmlFilesList(string path)
    {
        List<string> ListFileNames = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(path));

        return ListFileNames;
    }

    public XDocument GetXDoc(string selectedXmlFile)
    {
        XDoc = XDocument.Load(selectedXmlFile);

        return XDoc;
    }

    public XAttribute GetRootAttribute()
    {
        RootAttribute = XDoc.Root.Attribute("No");

        return RootAttribute;
    }

    public List<XElement> GetStepList()
    {
        StepList = XDoc.Root.Elements("Step").ToList();

        return StepList;
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean stepdata1 has the da the content of StepData2 ? And do mind asking me why you are using reverse casing for naming private variables and properties?

Comment: *Why* is `StepData` an instance field in `Steps`? That's where the sharing is happening but it would be useful to know what led to that choice

Comment: Can you please also include the XML file in your question? We need a [mcve].

Comment: @ chetan: yes theyre both had the same content. Sry i dont know what you mean with "reverse casing"

Comment: @Damien: This choice was a wrong choice ;)+

Comment: @ Enigmativity: i wasnt able to format the Xml File, sry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using instance fields in your classes when local variables will do. I'll do two fixes in `Steps`, I'll leave resolving similar issues in `XmlDoc` and other classes for you to do:

```
class Steps
{
    private List<XElement> StepList;

    //Remove this, only needed inside GetStepData
    //private readonly XAttribute[] StepData;

    //Remove this, not needed
    //private int AmountOfSteps = 0;

    private readonly int AmountOfStepAttributes = 3;

    public Steps(XmlDoc xmlDoc)
    {
        StepList = xmlDoc.GetStepList();
    }

    public XAttribute[] GetStepData(XElement step)
    {
        //Create a new array here
        var StepData = new XAttribute[AmountOfStepAttributes];
        StepData[0] = step.Attribute("name");
        StepData[1] = step.Attribute("stepNo");
        StepData[2] = step.Attribute("colorCode");

        return StepData;
    }

    public List<XElement> stepList
    {
        get { return StepList; }
    }

    public int amountOfSteps
    {
        get
        {
            //Just directly return the count
            return stepList.Count();
        }            
    }

    public int amountStepAttributes
    {
        get { return AmountOfStepAttributes; }
    }
```

The comments in the above should all be removed - they're just describing what's changed and why.

With your current code, you have a single array contained in `Steps` which is overwritten each time `GetStepData` is called. In my fixed code above, we allocate a new array each time it's called and only manipulate *that* array up until the end of that method call.

---

One non-obvious tip for you - turn on the option "Treat Warnings as Errors" for your projects. Simple code shouldn't be generating warnings and it should have flagged at least one issue in your `XmlDocs` class (that the instance member `ListFileNames` is initialised but never used)

Ob link Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You can use an object initializer with indices after `var StepData = new XAttribute[AmountOfStepAttributes];`.

Comment: Thank You Damien!